# Фонетический разбор

Tags: орфография, фонетика, транскрипция

У меня вопрос: почему у Розенталя [х ъ д]овой, а не [х а д]овой? Объясните мне, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово *ходовой* можно затранскрибировать так: [хъдΛвój].

Объясним, что значат непривычные символы:

1. [ъ] -- сверхкраткий звук, похожий на очень короткий звук [ы]. Обычно произносится в заударных позициях (то есть после слога, на который падает ударение), в слогах, стоящих во втором предударном слоге и до него; на письме обозначается, как правило, буквами *о* и *а*.
2. [Λ] -- менее краткий, чем [ъ], звук. Встречается в первом предударном слоге, а также в абсолютном начале слова, где гласный звук стоит первым.
3. [j] = [й].

Дело в том, что школьная транскрипция [хадавóй] не учитывает длительность звуков, но ведь в потоке речи все они произносятся по-разному: кто-то быстрее, а кто-то медленнее. Этот недочет исправлен в описанной ранее форме записи звуков.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже сказали, Розенталь использует академическую фонетическую нотацию, она немного отличается от школьной.

А ответ по сути таков. **Потому что это второй предударный** слог, там вторая ступень редуцирования. "О" переходит не в [Λ] (или в [а] - в школьной записи версии) как в первом предударном, а в сверхкраткий [Ъ].

Вот посмотрите, как это объясняют на уроках РКИ.
https://is.muni.cz/do/ped/kat/KRus/fonetika/ch06.html

Остальные подробности повторять не буду (см. Aer).